# Autocomplete multiple values hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete field and I have two problems.

I need to get the "ids" of the chosen categories. I send it by hidden field but when the user chooses more than one category the only id that remains is the id of the last category chosen. A newer id overrides the previous id. How do I solve this ?!

I also have another problem:
When the user deletes all the categories chosen, the hidden field is still filled.

Code snippet

```
 <input type="text" id="example-tags" name="categorie" class="input-tags" value="">
                <input type="hidden" id="cat-id" name="catid" />



var data = [{"value":"1","label":"PHP"},{"value":"2","label":"Python"},{"value":"3","label":"Java"},{"value":"4","label":"ActionScript"},{"value":"5","label":"LUA"}];


     $('#example-tags_tag').autocomplete({

    source: data,

    focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#example-tags_tag" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  },

    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#cat-id").val(ui.item.value);           


      return false;
    }

 });
```

It did not work well using the stack tools. Here the code online:
[Http: //localhost/testes/auto-complete.html](http://http:%20//localhost/testes/auto-complete.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overriding, you can append the values by concatenating it with some character like ',' and again explode it to get individual value like:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    if( $("#cat-id").val() != '' )
    {
        $("#cat-id").val( $("#cat-id").val() + ',' + ui.item.value);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#cat-id").val(ui.item.value);
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzq9fv4r/)